# Sharing MongoDB changes with a team

Tags: git, node.js, mongodb

I've recently been learning how to use MongoDB with Node.js, and have been wondering how I would go about sharing MongoDB changes with the rest of a team, for example, through a git repository.

If I needed, for example, a collection named `users` in MongoDB, and that collection had some documents containing the fields `givenName` and `familyName`, this would be quite easy to do since when each developer on the team runs the application, MongoDB will automatically create the collection and the fields as they are written in the code.

Now lets say that for some reason I need to rename both fields to `forename` and `surname`.

The application has been running for a while so all of the developers on the team have local copies of the `users` collection containing documents with the `givenName` and `familyName`; the same is true for the production server too.

From what I understand I can't simply change the field names in the code to use the new field names since we would then 'lose' any data that was being used in the old field names (by 'lose' I of course mean that we just wouldn't see the old data any more even though it still exists, as expected).

So I think I would have to also run a command in the MongoDB shell to rename the fields in all of the relevant documents.

But if I do this then only my local copy of the `users` collection is up to date.

When using MySQL we would either just share all of our changes over git in a SQL file that we would run when needed, or if it was available use migrations, for example in the Laravel framework in PHP.

Would we just do the same as we did with MySQL and keep a `changes.js` file that we run in the MongoDB shell?

Or is there a better way to do this, perhaps in the application code itself so that changes are automatically run when a developer runs the application?

In other words, what are the best practices for sharing MongoDB changes amongst team members?

Comment: Seems like a migrations script will be necessary for your needs if you need your test data to reflect the changes. It could be for the console, or even node.js as long as it processes the "schema" changes consistently. Or, you could just ignore the changes, and only worry about production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data migration is a huge pain for pretty much all persistence systems. There are two big strategies: lazy and eager migration.

For **lazy** migration, you'd need your code to be able to cope with **both the old and the new data structure**. Unfortunately, I don't know how the node.js mongodb driver works internally. In the C# driver, for instance, it's possible to register a custom serializer, define aliases or use C#'s getters and setters to enable this behavior. So the `Forename` field would be read from `givenName` *or* `Forename`, but when storing it back to the database it will always be serialized as `Forename`.

The problem with this strategy is that it doesn't work with queries, e.g. `{"Forename" : "John"}` would fail because some documents haven't been migrated yet. Indexes or even unique constraints make matters a lot worse of course.

The **eager** migration needs some kind of script that basically runs through all documents in the database and updates them according to your needs. Normally, this is the easier path and it won't break queries. However, you need to run this script at the right time, and for large datasets, this can take a while. During that time, your system is either down or delivers incorrect results.

Thus, the larger the amount of data, the more 'lazyness' must be allowed. For example, you might want to run the script per-user (rather than in natural order) so that it's very unlikely that a user hits a 'half-migrated' state of his data. Still, you'd want your code to be able to handle this.

For both strategies, when things get complicated, schema versioning might be required, i.e. individual documents have a field like `_sv` and there are scripts that know how to get from version `n` to version `n+1`. Then, you can make the scripts very abstract and idempotent so you can run them without having to fear that running the old script on the new data breaks anything.